# RTSP streaming IP camera MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, rtsp, live-streaming

Im trying to show a live stream from an ACTI IP camera on an android phone. The ACTI camera is set to stream H.264 Baseline with 320x240 resolution. An error keeps popping up after prepareAsync() is called.

```
W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died 
W/AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died! 
E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
```

I checked the URL format, tried removing the "?". I also tried the stream URL in VLC and it worked. Im running this on an Android Jelly Bean. Code is below

```
final static String RTSP_URL = "rtsp://192.168.34.52:7070?/";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vo_ipphone);

        mySurfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surface);


        Log.i(TAG, "prepare surface holder");
        _surfaceHolder = mySurfaceView.getHolder();
        _surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        _surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(320, 240);    
    }

@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Prepared!");
        _mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Surface created");
        _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        _mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                _mediaPlayer.release();
                //create another mediaplayer preferrably in another thread
                return false;
            }
        });
        _mediaPlayer.setDisplay(_surfaceHolder);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
        Uri source = Uri.parse(RTSP_URL);


        try {
            // Specify the IP camera's URL and auth headers.
            Log.i(TAG, "Set data source");
            _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers);
            //_mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, source);
            // Begin the process of setting up a video stream.
            Log.i(TAG, "set on prepared listener");
            _mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            Log.i(TAG, "prepare async");
            _mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

        _mediaPlayer.release();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like all line is true but Maybe error comes from wrong URL , url should like below

```
final static String RTSP_URL = "rtsp://192.168.34.52:7070/";
```

try this url without '?'

And also check your device internet and permission

Add to permission in AndroidManifest.xml if is not exist

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I hope it work

Comment: I have tried it without the "?" and gives me the same error. I also have the permission in the manifest file

Comment: @maryS
Did you check that video stream format supports android device ? [video format](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html)